# Obyener valor de React-Select con useState

Tags: reactjs, usestate, react-select

[![Este seria mi codigo][Aqui muestro mi documento donde con React-Select obtengo un valor pero no lo puedo guardar en una variable con el handleOnChange como en un imput]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXNBW.png)

Aqui muestro mi documento donde con React-Select obtengo un valor pero no lo puedo guardar en una variable con el handleOnChange como en un imput

Comment: Podrías poner el código como texto, [formateado](/help/formatting) por favor? Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880

Answer (score 0):

1. No se ponen imagenes del codigo. se inserta el codigo como texto.
2. En la funcion handleinputtipo, tienes mal puesta la funcion settipo. Sería `setTipo({...formTipo, [target.label]: target.value})`.
3. No se de que librería es ese select. Pero normalmente en las funciones onChange se recibe el evento, no target. osea que el valor sería `event.target.value` a no ser que el parametro que recibe la función lo pongas entre llaves `{target}`

Comment: Ya había visto el error de la función, solo que a diferencia del input con este select no puedo guardar el valor de mi estado en una variable, no se le asigna a mi estado inicial, y el evento no me manda la propiedad nombre solo el label y value de mi arreglo.